# Interface controller not found while creating a page-based interface

Tags: swift, watchkit, uistoryboard, watchos

I try to create a simple page-based interface for my watchOS app. I create the second view controller on my Storyboard and connect it with the first one using a relationship segue `next page` (which is the only option). After building the application I keep getting an error:

`Watch Extension[59686:1220414] [default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerWithID:]:2093: ComF: interfaceController for interfaceControllerID:E9260002 not found (clientIdentifier=(null))`.

The interface controller however are displayed and I can scroll through the pages, but the buttons stop working.

How can I fix it? With the single interface controller everyrhing works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

So I still have this error (warning) but I figured out how to make it work. The problem was that I mixed page-based interface with the hierarchical one. That is not supported by design. So I changed push segues to presentController and it worked for me